# Availability Calendar not working using Views

Tags: 7, datetime

I could not find this issue in the issue tracker for Availability Calendar module and I'm wondering if somebody has encountered this issue before.

I set up 'Page' Views for all 'Contents' of 'Property' type using 'Unformatted' list. The page includes the field 'Availability Calendar' and the calendar shows properly on the specified URL location with all the colors and what not. But when you click on a date to specify your booking nothing happens.

I think this is because I am not able to include the 'formlet' in the fields specification. But the 'formlet' has type 'none' on the content type.

Any thoughts or has anyone encountered the same problem before I raise this in the issue tracker?

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't rather be a bugreport? Just asking, because it looks like one. On the other hand you already visited issue queue and decided to post here, and I'm not sure why. If it looks like it should work, was examined against docs etc, then it usually is a bug, as far as my experience goes.

Comment: Hi @Mołot I could not find this in the issue tracker I thought It was never an issue and probably just some settings I might have missed or I'm just getting confused.